# Improve the performance of ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, pyes

I am using ElasticSearch to index some data. But I found that the performance is not that efficiency.

There are only 3000 entries data and each data has 6 columns. It costs 5 mins to index these 3000 entries.

Because I am new with ElasticSearch, my code and program flow are basic as following:

1. search and check is there any same data with it.
2. if there is same data, then update.
3. If not, then add.

The code is following:

```
conn = pyes.ES('server:9200')
```

Search:

```
searchResult = conn.search(searchDict, indexName, TypeName)
```

Index

```
conn.index(storeDict, indexName, TypeName, id)
```

Update the Count in the index data.

```
 conn.partial_update(indexName, TypeName, id, "ctx._source.Count += counter", params={"counter" : 1})
```

Is there any method that can improve the performance of my code ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you make the title of the question a little more descriptive. It seems more about improving the way you use elasticsearch in your application, than improving its own performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to search before updating. [Read the es docs on updating](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/update/) and scroll down to the `upsert` section. `upsert` is a parameter which holds a document to use **if the document does not exist on the server**, otherwise the `upsert` is ignored and it works like a normal `update` request (as you are doing now).

Good luck!

Comment: HI, It's me again. I revised my code with upsert and it's better. It costs 3 mins to finish. Is there any method to let the time less than 1 min ?

Comment: I change the config file in /bin/elasticsearch.in.sh, bit it's seems doesn't work even I restart the elasticsearch. How can I let elasticsearch read the new setting file ?

Comment: I'm not so sure about the settings files sorry. If you want to get the index time even lower then don't use an update script. What I would experiment with (if you are incrementing one field in the update) is to calculate the result of the modification, create a new document in pyres, then just overwrite the old document. (Use the normal put api, as you are doing in step 3 of your question.)

Comment: Also I forgot to mention, you should look at the `_bulk` [api from the es docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/bulk/)

Comment: It's unbelieveable, I use bulk size 400, and it cost only 2 secs to finish this job.

Comment: @Jimmy use bulk size 400? you mean when you created the connection, you did conn = ES("server:9200", bulk_size=400)? I did that but the performance is the same.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use [versioning feature](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/versioning/) of elasticsearch. If you are deciding your documents id's its pretty easy. It simply re-index the data.
- You should use BULK API for indexing.(1000-5000 is good)
- Another reason of bad performance is about configuration settings on `config/elasticsearch.yml`, you can use this [hints](https://gist.github.com/duydo/2427158) to increase indexing performance.